# Execute js function using websocket and wait to return value to python code and vice versa

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I am trying to build application that uses browser as the user interface, and python as the backend. The idea here is that I want to use something like websocket so send message to js code to execute some function and return its value back to python and vice versa. but the problem is that websocket is asynchronous and I don't get anything back except "undefined", how can I solve this problem or is there any idea other than that?
what I want to do is something like that:

```
socket= new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8765');
socket.onopen = function(){
    console.log("Server is open")
}
​

function exec_py(){
    socket.send("hi");
    // I want to wait for the message and take it as the return of the exec_py()
    socket.onmessage = function(s) {
      response = s 
    }
   
    return response
}
```